# TypeScript typings file node.d.ts versus index.d.ts

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've been experimenting with TypeScript on Node.js (and liking it a lot).

Somewhere along the way, I ended up with this node.d.ts which worked:

```
/// <reference path='./typings/main/ambient/node/node.d.ts' />
```

Today I started a fresh project and typings gave me this instead:

```
/// <reference path='./typings/main/ambient/node/index.d.ts' />
```

It works, but I am wondering why the file name is now index.d.ts instead of node.d.ts.

Comment: There's a note on the Typings Github page saying "Updating from 0.6 to 0.7? Make sure you rm -rf typings/ and re-install them, the directory structure has changed". I wonder if this has something to do with that?

Comment: I should probably ask the question at Typings Github, and then post the answer here.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me!

Answer (score 1):

This was in fact a recent intentional change by the Typings project maintainer.  You can read more about it here: https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/352